# CKEditor is not showing in Laravel 9 with Vite + Vue3 Project

Tags: vuejs3, vite, laravel-9, ckeditor5

After installing CKEditor5 alongside other necessary packages, I configure my vite.config.js based on this [document](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/frameworks/vuejs-v3.html#configuring-viteconfigjs).

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import ckeditor5 from '@ckeditor/vite-plugin-ckeditor5';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: 'resources/js/app.js',
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
        ckeditor5({ theme: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark') })
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    }
});
```

There are problems with this, and I cannot make my CKEditor up and running in my website.

I have tried some approaches as demonstrated below; however, it is not solving my problem.

1. The original configured guidelines has a problem stating that "[vite] fileURLToPath is not defined"
2. When I try to fix this error by importing fileURLToPath from 'url', the attached photo below is the problem I encounter:
   [image: Error when importing fileURLToPath from 'url']
3. If I remove code related to fileURLToPath entirely, I get an error shown below:
   [image: Error when removing code related to fileURLToPath entirely]

Comment: Remove the resolve object and the fileURLtoPath import from your Vite config. Then import CKEditor into the Vue component where it's being used.

Comment: any updated? did you resolved?